# View form surroundet with ng-if is clearing model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to send some data from a form to my controller. Surrounded in the template file with an if. So my working example (without ng-if) is:

**View**

```
<form ng-submit="activate()">
    <div class="md-form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="input.password" required>
        <label>Password</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn primary btn-block p-x-md">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.showDescription1 = false;
$scope.activate = function() {
    console.log($scope.input);
    return;
    ...
}
```

**Result**

It is what I expect... The model object with password field. So now the problem: When I wrapped all the view with an ng-if, the console.log will write undefined.

**Modified view**

```
<div ng-if="!showDescription1" class="m-b text-sm">
    <span>
        This is the second description...
    </span>

    <form ng-submit="activate()">
        <div class="md-form-group">
            <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="input.password" required>
            <label>Password</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn primary btn-block p-x-md">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Controller**

(no change)

**Result**

The console.log call will write the undefined value. I don't know why, but the ng-if statement is clearing my model? However why?

Comment: [I can't reproduce it](https://plnkr.co/edit/nVCmukG5abpi1Y4ZHkrq?p=preview). You probably have not included some other code. Please, update [the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nVCmukG5abpi1Y4ZHkrq?p=preview)

Comment: Where/how do you setup `$scope.input`?

Comment: @David did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-if` will attach the element to DOM when the expression `ng-if="!showDescription1"` is evaluated as `true` and removes the element when it evaluates to `false'. For this reason any of your user input will be lost.

For your case, you need to use `ng-show` or `ng-hide` which will not re-render the element and instead change their `display`. So the user input persists.

Answer (score 1):

**ng-if** creates its own child scope whenever it evaluates to true. So the value of "input" you are logging in console.log is inside the new child scope created by the ng-if and not the controller scope. 
Below description from angular documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) explains it :

> Note that when an element is removed using ngIf its scope is destroyed
>   and a new scope is created when the element is restored. The scope
>   created within ngIf inherits from its parent scope using prototypal
>   inheritance. An important implication of this is if ngModel is used
>   within ngIf to bind to a javascript primitive defined in the parent
>   scope. In this case any modifications made to the variable within the
>   child scope will override (hide) the value in the parent scope.

Now, to get your code working , use $parent to the model as shown below :

```
 <div ng-if="!showDescription1" class="m-b text-sm">
   <span>
     This is the second description...
   </span>

<form ng-submit="activate()">
    <div class="md-form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="$parent.input.password" required>
        <label>Password</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn primary btn-block p-x-md">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it is working as per your expectation :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
  $scope.showDescription1 = false;
  $scope.activate = function() {
    console.log($scope.input);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-if="!showDescription1" class="m-b text-sm">
    <span>
        This is the second description...
    </span>
  <form ng-submit="activate()">
    <div class="md-form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="input.password" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn primary btn-block p-x-md">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```